# Most efficient way to search integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm looking for the most efficient way to determine whether a specific value exists in a small (16 element) array of integers in Java. The array is unsorted.

Options:

1. A boring but reliable for loop
2. Sort the array then Arrays.binarySearch(arr, targetVal)
3. List.contains method  - example  Arrays.asList(arr).contains(targetVal)
4. Something else.

Option 3 must have some overhead in "converting" to a List but I could use a List throughout rather than an array if that would be better overall. I've no feel for how List performs speed wise.

Comment: KISS principle `->` For only 16 elements a boring loop it's just enough

Comment: Such a small array usually fints into the CPU's L1 cache row so your fastest way is to simply for loop over it.

Comment: Option 1, unless you sort it only once and then you are going to search it many times, in which case option 2.

Comment: Unless you identify the array searching as an important hotspot in your software, it doesn't matter one bit. As soon as you do anything more complex (data access, calculations, etc.), any differences in array searching performance is lost and any time you've spent on this is wasted.

Comment: @Kayaman your response applies to any and all performance related questions and so has no value. We don't need to ask for every single performance question whether they have checked the rest of the system.

Comment: @rghome it's important knowledge for the beginners (and bad programmers) who think that micro-optimization matters, parallelization makes things automatically faster, don't understand differences between CPU and IO constrained work and so on. Also, I wasn't asking, I was telling.

Comment: Thanks folks. And, yes, the only reason I'm worrying about it is that I'm in an audio processing function that fires 48,000 times per second, once per sample, so for-loops make me a bit twitchy. It's actually working fine but if I could shave a few cycles off it then so much the better.

Comment: Normally, audio processing is done on small blocks, rather than once per sample.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't design the framework and SDK of this particular (commercially successful) project. I'm just a third party dev making plugins for it so I focus on what I can control rather than what I can't.

Answer (score 3):

Based on condition that the array is unsorted any search on it will have complexity O(n).
You can try use your second assumption. In that case you will have O(n*log(n)) + O(log(n))
But if you have such small array and you want to search only once better to use a simple loop. Because it hard to predict what time will be elapsed for conversion to List or what type of sorting algorithm will you use and etc.
Just a loop will be a good choice

FYI: Stream will not be efficient at your case.

Comment: Obviously, O(n*log(n)) + O(log(n)) is not better than O(n), so it’s not really worth a try.